# How to insert steamid into database using the steam api

Tags: php, html, steam-web-api, forms, http-post

I am trying to log the users name, email, and region as well as their `steamid` via an html form.

The html form is here:

```
<form class="cptxt" action="/insert.php" method="post">
PUBG NAME: <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter In Game 
Name">
<br><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email"><br><br>
SteamID: <input type="text" name="sid" value="<?php echo 
$steamprofile['steamid'] ?>" ><br><br>
SELECT REGION: &nbsp;
<select name="region">
<option value="NA">North America</option>
<option value="EU">Europe</option>
<option value="AS">Aisa</option>
<option value="OC">Oceianic</option>
</select>  <br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is the insert.php file

```
<?php

require('connect.php');
include ('steamauth/userInfo.php');

if(!$con)
{
    echo "NOT CONNECTED";
}

if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'pubgfinder'))
{
    echo "db not selected";
}


$Name = $_POST['username'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$Sid = $_POST['sid']
$Region = $_POST['region'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (Name,Email,Region,Sid) VALUES 
('$Name','$Email','$Region','$Sid')";
if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    echo "NOT INSERTED";
}
else
{
    echo "INSERTED";
}

header("refresh:2; url=home.php");

?>
```

So far what I get is the form working, besides the `steamid` part of it. It writes the `steamid` into the form field as well, but doesn't send to the database.
Please help. Am I writing this wrong? What's the issue here?

Comment: What if i create a php variable inside the insert.php file and then insert it to the db? is this possible?

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: `$Sid = $_POST['sid']` is missing a semicolon. That should be raising a syntax error and causing PHP to crash before the script has started to run. If adding a semicolon there fixes this, do you mind if we close this for being a 'simple typographical error'?

Comment: @HPierce i fixed the semi colon lol however i still get the not inserted error. i have the steamid field in the table set as varchar 100 btw.

Comment: UPDATE** please close this was a small silly error question I have fixed it... i feel a bit ashamed lol. thanks for the help too!